# firebase signInWithCredential from FacebookAuthProvider error

Tags: facebook, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

Hi, I'm building a react-native app with Expo. Authentication is handled via Firebase. The user has the ability to sign up with Facebook. So the FB token needs to passed down to firebase. I'm testing in iOS. Firebase auth without FB is working. Facebook login works. Passing the FB token to firebase returns "auth/internal-error".

- Firebase FB auth is enabled and has the correct details (app id, secret)
- Facebook "Valid OAuth redirect URIs" is set to the one from Firebase
- Client OAuth Login, Web OAuth Login are set to yes - and I toggled them for all cases with the same error.
- Expo app has the correct facebookScheme, facebookAppId, facebookDisplayName in app.json

I'm using Expos   "logInWithReadPermissionsAsync"   function to get the users FB details.

Response:

```
{type: "success", token: "EAAaX8y1lhFkBAO1MJZCTDzSjVCOjAjZCVJrWnNhyUVsgqdLlZ…
yVnAWDPap1ZBHzJUWwK4VpZAZCtEH9grVcFebjK2ekxZCxmx", expires: 1517634962}
```

I parse the response with:

```
const provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
...
const credential = provider.credential(response.token);
```

const credential becomes:

```
{idToken: "EAAaX8y1lhFkBAO1MJZCTDzSjVCOjAjZCVJrWnNhyUVsgqdLlZ…
yVnAWDPap1ZBHzJUWwK4VpZAZCtEH9grVcFebjK2ekxZCxmx", providerId: 
"facebook.com"}
```

I call firebase signInWithCredential with credential:

```
const auth = firebase.auth();
...
auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
.then((user) => {
  console.log('signInWithCredential success', user.providerData);
})
.catch((err) => {
   console.log('signInWithCredential error', err);
});
```

The error response is:

```
code: "auth/internal-error", message: "{"error":{"errors":
[{"domain":"global","reason":"invalid":400,"message":"A system error has 
occurred"}}"}
```

I triple checked if all Firebase/Facebook settings and values are correct. It looks like a firebase issue as FB login works. Firebase auth with "createUserWithEmailAndPassword" also works. It's only "signInWithCredential" making trouble.

Full function:

```
import { Facebook } from 'expo';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
....
const firebaseConfig = {
 apiKey: 'xxxx',
 authDomain: 'xxxx',
 databaseURL: 'xxxx',
 projectId: 'xxxx',
 storageBucket: 'xxxx',
 messagingSenderId: 'xxxx',
};
...
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
...
const auth = firebase.auth();
const provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
....
// on botton press
handleFacebookButton() {
 Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync(FACEBOOK_APP_ID, {
  permissions: ['public_profile', 'email'],
 })
  .then((response) => {
    console.log('logInWithReadPermissionsAsync success', response);

    if (response.type === 'success') {
      // Firebase credential is created with the Facebook access token.
      const credential = provider.credential(response.token);
      console.log('FB SUCCESS', credential);
      auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
        .then((user) => {
          console.log('signInWithCredential success', user.providerData);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log('signInWithCredential error', err);
        });
    } else {
      console.log('something went wrong on facebook auth', response);
    }
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log('error', err);
    this.setState({
      error: err.message,
      loading: false,
    });
  });
```

}

Comment: Hmm, the underlying facebook credential should have an `accessToken` field and not an `idToken` field. Does it make a difference if you initialize the credential as follows: `const cred = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(response.token);`

Comment: Thanks, I saw it in the docs but it only returns a idToken. I tried `const credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(response.token‌);` without the instance of `new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();` which throws `"First argument "token" must be a valid string or a valid object."`. I have a feeling code wise it looks all good, it's only that I don't receive the `accessToken` back from `FacebookAuthProvider`. What I did for now is `credential.accessToken = response.token;` - so I add the `accessToken` manually based on the `idToken` - and it works! But it's a hack I think.

Comment: This is a hack. You should not rely on it as they could change underlying implementation Are you passing an object to `credential`? I just tested: `firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential('accessToken')` and it populated correctly. The argument must be a string.

Comment: Hi, yes I'm passing a string. `response.token` is typeOf `string`. I tried to call `credential ` exactly how you do it - directly - so `firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(response.token)`and I get an error `"FacebookAuthProvider failed: Expected 0 arguments but got 1."`. I'm using a instance of `firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider` called provider -> `const provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();` and call 'const credential = provider.credential(response.token);' - no error, bit no accessToken. Can you try it with `new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider`?

Comment: Also, I'm importing firebase like `import * as firebase from 'firebase';` - and use it with `const auth = firebase.auth();` and `const provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();` - something wrong here?

Comment: What version of Firebase are you using?

Comment: Sorry, should have added it before - `"firebase": "^4.7.0",`

Comment: I think there is an issue. If you call `firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential('accessToken')`, it works but if you use `new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider().credential('accessToken')`, it doesn't. I think this is because of the underlying superclass OAuthProvider which initializes credentials with 2 arguments (id token and access token).

Comment: That's it! Thank you

Comment: @bojeil: you're a lifesaver! Couldn't find the answer to this anywhere.